# How to get bind value in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having difficulty to get model.title's value and display it into console when click event triggered. For example,there is total 3 records into my json file.The first model's title name is IRIS.When I click on link then I want to also display it on console. Can anyone help me please.

```
<div id="app">

            <div v-for="model in myData">

          <h1>{{model.title}}</h1>
          <p>{{model.project}}</p>
          <p>{{model.bedrooms}}</p>
          <a href="#" @click="getTitle">View Detail</a>


        </div>


    </div>

 var vm = new Vue({

        el:'#app',
        data:{
            myData:[]

        },
        created:function(){
        this.fetchData();
        this.getTitle();
         },

        methods:{
        fetchData: function(){
        var url='data.json';
        axios.get(url)
        .then(function(res){
        vm.myData= res.data.models;
        console.log(this.myData);

        });
     },
     getTitle:function() {
        var url='j.json';
        axios.get(url)
        .then(function(res){
        //vm.myData= res.data.models.getTitle;
        console.log(res.data.models.getTitle);

        });

     }

}



    });
```

The below code is from data.json file

```
{
    "models": [
      {
        "title": "IRIS",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "SINGLES",
        "bedrooms": 3

      },
      {
        "title": "LILAC",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "DOUBLE",
        "bedrooms": 4

      },
      {
        "title": "ASTER",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "SINGLES",
        "bedrooms": 4

      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass variable in method called on click

like this:
`<a href="#" @click="getTitle(model)">View Detail</a>`

and then in method:

`getTitle:function(model) {
   console.log(model);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="model in myData">
    <h1>{{model.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{model.project}}</p>
    <p>{{model.bedrooms}}</p>
    <a href="#" @click="getTitle(model)">View Detail</a>
  </div>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data(){
    return {
      myData:[]
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  methods:{
    fetchData () {
      let vm = this;
      var url='data.json';
      axios.get(url)
       .then(function(res){
         vm.myData = res.data.models;
         console.log(vm.myData);
       });
    },
    getTitle (model) {
      console.log(model.title)
    }
  }
});
```

Just change some of your code. You can take `model` as parameter in `getTitle` function. You dont have to call it in `mounted` hook